# neighborhood classification with postgis

Tags: google-maps, gis, geospatial, postgis, geojson

I need to build a web application to explore some survey data, but I am struggeling a bit to find the right tools. PostGIS looks quite interesting, but I am not sure if it fits my needs or is maybe overkill.

The dataset (table 1) contains rows (events in Los Angeles) with a spatial attribute, i.e. a long/lat field. I have another dataset (table 2) defining areas in [Los Angeles](http://projects.latimes.com/mapping-la/about/#the-data). Can I do the following in PostGIS?

- SELECT only the datapoints from table 1 from a certain area defined in table 2?
- Tabulate a categorical variable by area? E.g count number of males and females for every area?
- Do binning of a numeric variable by area? E.g. to get the age distribution, show how many people per area are of age [0-9), [10-19), [20-29), etc?

Furthermore, I was wondering if it is safe to have the PostGIS database directly queried by javascript (using geojson), or should I always have an application layer in between (code injection ,etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your points is yes, yes, and yes.  After installing PostGIS, you will be able to do all of this (assuming table 1 has these attributes).

SELECT only the datapoints from table 1 from a certain area defined in table 2?

- Yes, in a few manners.  Is the data in table 2 defined as polygons, or is it a list of points?  List of points is a bit harder to do, but works...much easier if you have polygons here.  (after looking at your link,  use the shape (shp) file.

Tabulate a categorical variable by area? E.g count number of males and females for every area?

- Count is in the select clause, the geo component is in the where clause.  As long as these attributes exist in table 1, you can do these counts by any value you want.

Do binning of a numeric variable by area? E.g. to get the age distribution, show how many people per area are of age [0-9), [10-19), [20-29), etc?

- Yep, same answer as above.  Binning might require a case statement, but as long as you can group by it, you can count by it.  heh

Not sure if I can answer the last question though...